# Is there any class to diagnose invoked method in a java class?

Tags: java

1. I need to diagnose all invoked methods in a class(either declared in the class or not)  using it's source code. Means that give the class source code to a method as an input and get the invoked method by the class as the output. In fact I need a class/method which operates same as java lexical analyzer . 
   Is there any method to diagnose all invoked methods ?
2. of course I tried to use Runtime.traceMethodCalls(); to solve the problem but there was no output. I've read I need to run java debug with java -g  but unfortunately when I try to run java -g it makes error. Now what should I do ? Is there any approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize one of the open source static analyzers for Java as a starting point. [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) allows you to build your own modules. [Soot](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/) has a pretty flexible API and a good example of [call analysis](http://www.bodden.de/2008/09/22/soot-intra/). [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) might also allow you too write a custom module. AFAIK all three are embeddable in the form of a JAR, so you can incorporate whatever you come up with into your own custom program.

Comment: Soot needs to add manually each class which participates in an app and often generates incomplete call graph. another difficulty in soot is that Soot make dynamic call graph not static. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Hmmm, thought Soot used a starting class for it's trace analysis and then pulled in dependent classes as it encountered them, as long as said classes existed in it's classpath. But it's been awhile, I'll have to check the API again.

Comment: Yes, It needs a starting node to make call graph. Follows are the statements I used to add classes. Scene.v().setEntryPoints(entryPoints);
        Scene.v().addBasicClass("java.lang.Object", SootClass.BODIES);
        Scene.v().addBasicClass("MySets_MyWork.FunctionCalls", SootClass.BODIES);
        Scene.v().addBasicClass("java.lang.String", SootClass.BODIES);
        soot.Main.main(args);            If a class is not added in the code, an exception will occur and notify that the class ... must be added before calling soot.Main. ... .

Comment: @zari - did you try the loadClassAndSupport() method? I haven't invoked the soot.Main directory like that before, but addBasicClass doesnt pull in dependencies.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. Using your answers, I wrote a code segment which generates dynamic call graph. Now I encountered another problem. As I said before, Soot generates dynamic call graph. I only need static call graph of an app. How can I obtain static call graph for my apps? Generating dynamic call graph consumes a huge portion of time and generates many useless information.

Answer (score 5):

1) In the general case, no. [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html) will always allow the code to make method calls that you won't be able to analyze without actually running the code.

2) Tracing the method calls won't give you the full picture either, since a method is not in any way guaranteed (or even likely) to make ***all*** the calls it can every time you call it.

Your best bet is some kind of "best effort" code analysis. You may want to try enlisting the compiler's help with that. For example, compile the code and analyze the generated class file for all emitted external symbols. It won't guarantee catching every call (see #1), but it will get you close in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it is hard to determine what is exactly problem you're trying to solve.
But in case:

1. If you want to analyze source code, to see which parts of it are redundant and may be removed, then you could use some IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition etc.) In IDE's you have features to search for usages of method and also you have functionality to analyze code and highlight unused methods as warnings/errors.
2. If you want to see where during runtime some method is called, then you could use profiling tool to collect information on those method invocations. Depending on tool you could see also from where those methods were called. But bare in mind, that when you execute program, then it is not guaranteed that your interesting method is called from every possible place.
3. if you are developing an automated tool for displaying calling graphs of methods. Then you need to parse source and start working with code entities. One way would be to implement your own compiler and go on from there. But easier way would be to reuse opensourced parser/compiler/analyzer and build your tool around it.

   - I've used IntelliJ IDEA CE that has such functionalitys and may be downloaded with source http://www.jetbrains.org/display/IJOS/Home
   - Also there is well known product Eclipse that has its sources available.

   Both of these products have enormous code base, so isolating interesting part would be difficult. But it would still be easier than writing your own java compiler and werifying that it works for every corner case.

Comment: As I explained in my question, I merely want to know which method invokes which ones by analyzing it's source code.

Comment: Yes. I got that, but what remains to be unclear is the context in which you wish to accomplish that task. If you need to look through just one project, then going with some IDE is acceptable solution. But in case you want to create some kind of automated tool for example to verify that students don't too much submit redundant code as their solutions. Or to verify that your subcontractors don't create redundant code just to get code line count up, then you'd need some kind of automatic service that would analyze source in background and then alert you about unused methods in code.

Comment: Surely I'm developing an automated tool for software architecture. It gets .java files as input and generates output. The tool must diagnose static call graph for the code.

Answer (score 0):

For analyzing the bytecode as mentioned above you could take a look at **JBoss Bytecode**. It is more for testing but may also be helpful for analyzing code.

[sven.malvik.de](http://sven.malvik.de)

Answer (score 0):

You may plug into the compiler.

Have a look the source of Project Lombok for instance. 
There is no general mechanism, so they have one mechanism for javac and one for eclipse's compiler.

http://projectlombok.org/